# Top 3 Scores - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm building a "Top 3 Scores" Leaderboard. I want to display the top three scores, drawing the max per person, but I don't want to limit 3, because I want to display anyone that has the top 3 scores. So for example, with the data below,

```
+----+-----+
|Name|Score|
+----+-----+
|Matt|   17|
|Mark|   29|
|Luke|   28|
|John|   29|
|Paul|   27|
|Matt|   29|
|Mark|   22|
+----+-----+
```

I want to display:

```
+------+-----+
|Name  |Score|
+------+-----+
|1.Matt|   30|
|2.Mark|   29|
|2.John|   29|
|3.Luke|   28|
+------+-----+
```

My first thought is to extract the max for everyone, and then stop displaying after the score changes (using PHP).

```
select name, max(score)
from SCORES
group by name
order by name
```

Is there any way to do this directly in SQL?

Comment: If I wasn't on my phone I would answer but the way I would I do it is selet the top 3  distinct numerical scoresscores and put them in a tmp table then join that tmp table in a select like above.

Comment: @AdamGent You think a temp table is better than a subquery like all the other answers that have been posted?

Comment: A sub query is a tmp table :) and I meant either I just can't type on my iPhone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT name, score
FROM SCORES
JOIN (SELECT distinct score score3
      FROM scores
      ORDER BY score DESC
      LIMIT 2, 1) x
ON score >= score3
ORDER by score DESC
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b7a0/5)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name,score
    FROM SCORES
    WHERE score in (
        SELECT distinct s.score
        FROM SCORES as s
        ORDER BY s.score desc
        LIMIT 3)
    )
    ORDER BY score
```

Comment: The offset component of `LIMIT` is 0-based, so you're off by 1.

Comment: @Barmar you're right. Just get top 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  Name, MAX(Score) Score
FROM    TableName a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    TableName b
            WHERE   a.Score = b.Score
            GROUP   BY Score
            ORDER   BY Score DESC
            LIMIT   3
        )
GROUP   BY Name
ORDER   BY Score DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5541a/6)

OUTPUT based on the records given above

```
╔══════╦═══════╗
║ NAME ║ SCORE ║
╠══════╬═══════╣
║ Mark ║    29 ║
║ John ║    29 ║
║ Matt ║    29 ║
║ Luke ║    28 ║
║ Paul ║    27 ║
╚══════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE score IN (SELECT DISTINCT score FROM mytable ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3)
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: Wrong types of quotes

Comment: fixed - thanks: added a DESC where needed

Comment: you ave syntax error in your code, `WHERE` should come first before `ORDER`, second if you fix that, you will receive an error `MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery`

Comment: I'm not sure this is a MySQL Specific question, and I don't know this limitation on other SQL applications.

Answer (score 1):

this will give the top three scores, regardless of ties.

SELECT `score` FROM `mytable` group by score
ORDER BY `score` DESC
LIMIT 3

now get the third score.

SELECT MIN(`score') FROM (SELECT`score`FROM`mytable`group by score
ORDER BY`score` DESC
LIMIT 3) as top3

finally get everything equal or above the third score

SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `score' >=
(SELECT MIN(`score') FROM 
(SELECT `score` FROM `mtyable` group by `score'
ORDER BY`score` DESC
LIMIT 3) as top3)

Answer (score 1):

Here IS [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b7a0/11).

```
SELECT
  NAME,
  score
FROM SCORES
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(score,(SELECT
                           SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT score ORDER BY score DESC),',',3)
                         FROM SCORES)) > 0
ORDER BY score desc
```