# How to select top 3 highscore in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a 'users' table as follow.

```
id  name    gender  highscore
1   Smith   male    5
2   David   male    8   
3   Ken     female  15
4   Trump   male    8
5   Jone    male    4
6   Nicoel  male    6
7   Ben     male    32
8   Micale  male    5
9   Stancu  male    6
```

I want to select users information that exists within top 3 highest score. Scores may be duplicate but the result only depends on top 3 highest score, I mean that the result should be

```
id  name    gender  highscore
7   Ben     male    32
3   Ken     female  15  
2   David   male    8
4   Trump   male    8
```

I am trying following query but it is only get highest users.

```
select * from `users` where `highscore`=(select max(`highscore`) from users);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL's alternative to T-SQL's WITH TIES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469107/mysqls-alternative-to-t-sqls-with-ties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try the following query.

```
SELECT name, highscore 
FROM users JOIN (
  SELECT distinct highscore score3 
  FROM users 
  ORDER BY highscore DESC LIMIT 2, 1) x ON highscore >= score3 
ORDER by highscore DESC ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try order by with limit :

```
select * from `users` order by `highscore` desc limit 3
```

Comment: limit 3 only return 3 rows, as above question, this query only return to David.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16870911/8035209).
I tested and confirmed. Here is my output and query.[image]

```
SELECT name, highscore 
FROM users 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(highscore, (
   SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(
     DISTINCT highscore ORDER BY highscore DESC),',',3) 
   FROM users)) > 0 
ORDER BY highscore desc
```

Answer (score -3):

*SQL-transact syntax:*

```
select top 3 * from users order by highscore desc
```

*mySQL syntax :*

```
select * from `users` order by `highscore` desc limit 3
```

*Oracle syntax :*

```
select * from users where ROWNUM <= 3 order by highscore desc
```

Comment: this is for sql server